# GUI Automation in RDP

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, rdp, pywinauto

Can anyone of you help me with an automation task which involves connecting through rdp and automating certain task in a particular application which is stored in that server.

I have found scripts for rdp connection and for Windows GUI automation seperately.

But in the integration, I have become a bit confused.

It will be great if anyone can help me with the python library name :)

Comment: The question is not clear. Which scripts did you found? And what is already tried?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I found scripts with pywin auto which can automate Windows based applications in my system. "But pywinauto cannot control remote application. You need a pywinauto copy on
remote machine to run it with your app." I am not clear with this idea.

Comment: RDP doesn't provide any remote GUI context to the local machine. So Python+pywinauto has to be installed on remote machine where the target app should be automated. But you can't minimize RDP window (GUI context will be lost).

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Can u please help me know of some other automation techniques for the same requirment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to automate a RDP window using pywinauto as RDP window itself is an image of a desktop. Printing control identifiers of the RDP window gives the UI of the screen.

Solution is to install python+pywinauto in the remote machine.